Inconsistent “unzip -l … | grep -q …” results with pipefail
The following Bash function gave inconsistent results:
# $1    Path to ZIP archive.
# Exits with 0 status iff it contains a “.mp3” or “.flac” file.
mp3_or_flac_in_zip() {
    local archive=${1:?No archive given.}
    (
        set -o pipefail
        unzip -l "$archive" | grep -iqE '.\.(flac|mp3)$'
    )
}

When run n times in a row on the same music-containing ZIP, it randomly reported that there was no music in it (about 1–5 % of the time, but it varied greatly across ZIPs).
Switching to an intermediate variable instead of a pipe (with && instead of set -o pipefail to still make sure unzip was running fine) fixed the inconsistencies:
# $1    Path to ZIP archive.
# Exits with 0 status iff it contains a “.mp3” or “.flac” file.
mp3_or_flac_in_zip() {
    local archive=${1:?No archive given.}
    local listing
    listing=$(unzip -l "$archive") &&
    grep -iqE '.\.(flac|mp3)$' <<< "$listing"
}

What could be the issue, there? And are there other contexts where pipes are not such a good idea?

Unrelated: You need to double quote the expansion when assigning to archive and using local at the same time.

Does it matter if it's unzip or grep that fails? If either of them fail, there is no music file in the archive. I don't see the point of the pipefail in this intance.

@Kusalananda : Wouldn't you want to know that unzip failed for another reason?

@shellter, I wouldn't (not more than what unzip would output upon failure anyway), and it seems the code in the question does not attempt to distinguish between the two failures.  It's as if one would do an existence test on a file and a writability test on the destination path before copying it with cp.  What's the point of that if cp already takes care of it and outputs well-recognisable error messages?

@Kusalananda Regarding double quotes: As far as I know, the right-hand side of assignments is not subjected to word-splitting (except if there are hardcoded spaces outside of variables, of course), even when using declare, local, export, readonly, etc. As a matter of fact, ShellCheck does not give warnings in such contexts, and I never got issues with that even with ugly data filled with whitespace, newlines and so on. Example: f() { local x=$1; printf '[%q]\n' "$x"; }; f $'a\n \t b\n\nc  ' yields [$'a\n \t b\n\nc  '] just as expected.

@Kusalananda Regarding the relevancy of pipefail and whether we should be able to determine which program failed: To be honest, I’m not too sure myself. I wrote the initial function years ago, and it’s true that a failing unzip probably won’t print any grep-matching line anyway. Perhaps I was just too fond of over-fancy stuff back in those days; now I like the simpler version. Also, I use that on Bandcamp and Amazon Music downloads and I have yet to see unzip failing on any of those ZIPs (outside of those pipe-induced kills). Still, I think this made for an interesting study-case.

I integrated into my self-answer the fact that pipefail was hardly useful there to begin with, all things considered. Thanks for making me face the hard truth. xD

It basically looks like another case of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120263/why-exit-code-141-with-grep-q, which I found by looking into the return status that I was getting (141).
In some runs, unzip seems to have “enough time” to finish its job, while in other runs, it gets killed by grep because grep quickly finds a match. Since pipefail was on, this associates an error status to the whole foo | bar command suite. It follows that it’s probably possible to run into similar issues with virtually any foo | grep -q combined with pipefail.
The discrepancies in terms of failure probability between the ZIPs may be due to the number of files in those ZIPs (shorter vs. longer lists) and to the position of the first grep-matching file in those lists.
The foo_output=$(foo) approach ensures foo always has the opportunity of finishing its job without getting killed, but of course it can lead to lower performances (grep -q killing the input command after the first match is intentional and saves time and resources).
Arguably lame compromise
Still use a pipe, but without pipefail, and capture stderr to check that it’s empty, and assume that an absence of errors or warnings means that unzip ran fine. The main issue I see there is that it could lead to failures due to basic warnings associated with non-fatal quirks of specific ZIPs, but this is, to some extent, also the case with the other approaches from the question, I think:
err=$(
    {
        foo | grep -q …
    } 2>&1
) &&
[[ -z $err ]]

(This makes me wonder if there are better ways to check for the presence of specific kinds of files within a ZIP. That seems highly probable.)
Edit: More realistic approach
As pointed out by discussions on that page, the usefulness of pipefail in that context is dubious at best, as anyway a failing unzip will not output (on stdout) anything that would satisfy the grep. Furthermore, if something displeases unzip, the reason will probably appear via stderr. And to make things even more interesting, non-fatal issues (which tend to yield non-zero statuses according to man unzip) will not prevent us from finding files either, this way.
Final thoughts
IMHO, this is yet another argument to say that we should not toggle countless Bash flags all the time without being very aware of potential consequences, even if some multi-purpose “script templates” advertise set -o pipefail and set -e (among other things) as ways to magically avoid bugs. For each issue they avoid, they generally create double the amount of potential issues if you don’t keep your eyes peeled (and things get even worse in a company environment where you can’t force everyone to spend a day reading man bash). I still occasionally fall into caveats such as this one after years of scripting. In the present case, I thought using a ( … ) subshell to keep the pipefail effect as local as possible would keep me safe, only to stumble on an issue within the subshell, right under my nose.

I have never seen set -e or shopt -s pipefail avoid bugs. Both seem to generate more grief than necessary, especially when the developer is not 100% clear on what they do.

@Kusalananda not bugs, but it does solve the problems that are similar to "if you can't read the list of files that should be kept, don't delete all the other files". It's not a bug if you don't implement that, necessarily – sometimes that might be the behaviour you want – but it's exactly what you need to do if you need to abort early before you finally do one big destructive thing (for example, if you gather all the facts to change your partition table, you definitely want to fail before you reach the point where you actually change partition tables if anything before went wrong)

@MarcusMüller Well, what you mention are situations where a developer might choose to use set -e after considering their options (to explicitly test the exit codes of critical statements). Note that this is not the scenario that my comment was about. I have never seen set -e "avoid bugs".  Bugs cannot be avoided by using these options.  Bugs are avoided by writing robust code.

You can do:
mp3_or_flac_in_archive() (
  archive=${1?No archive given.}
  set -o pipefail
  bsdtar tf - < "$archive" | grep -iE '[^/]\.(flac|mp3)$' > /dev/null
)

For grep to read the whole input (finding all matches and reporting them, which we discard, even if we only care about whether there's been at least one) and avoid bsdtar being killed by a SIGPIPE after grep exits after the first match.
I've replaced unzip with libarchive's bsdtar CLI interface as unzip cannot process arbitrary file paths since it interprets wildcards¹. That also means we can process other types of archive.
I've moved the archive variable assignment inside the subshell, so we don't need the non-standard local, and the ${var?error} only exits that subshell, so the function rather than the whole script.
And I've replaced . with [^/] so as to avoid matching on path/to/.flac as I presume was your intention with that ..
In any case, if you want to check that both unzip/bsdtar and grep succeed, because for instance, you want to be able to detect a corrupted archive even if some .mp3 files could be found, then you need to let unzip/bsdtar run through the end, so you need  to consume all its output.
Besides switching from grep -q to grep > /dev/null, as a more generic approach, you could do:
(set -o pipefail
  bsdtar... | (
    grep -q pattern; ret=$?
    cat>/dev/null # consume and discard the remaining output if any
    exit "$ret"
  )
)

An alternative to getting bsdtar / unzip to print the full list of archive members and processing it with grep, you could use bsdcpio to list only the members you want and just check that there's some output:
mp3_or_flac_in_archive() (
  archive=${1?No archive given.}
  output=$(
    <"$archive" bsdcpio --quiet -it '*[^/].[mM][pP]3' '*[^/].[fF][lL][aA][cC]'
  ) && [ -n "$output" ]
)

Or:
mp3_or_flac_in_archive() (
  archive=${1?No archive given.}
  set -o pipefail
  <"$archive" bsdcpio --quiet -it '*[^/].[mM][pP]3' '*[^/].[fF][lL][aA][cC]' |
    awk 'END{exit !NR}'
)

Now, a problem with that approach is that it will return true even if all the files that have a name ending in .mp3 or .flac are of type directory. The bsdtar|grep approach would have excluded those as in bsdtar listing, files of type directory appear with a / appended to their name. There's a similar problem, regardless of the approach with symlinks.

Note that as an alternative to a subshell, since bash 4.4, you can use local - like in the Almquish shell or like the set -o localoptions of zsh for the changes to option settings (only those set by set, not the ones set by shopt) to be local to the function:
mp3_or_flac_in_archive() {
  local - archive=${1?No archive given.}
  set -o pipefail
  ...
}

Same as zsh's:
mp3_or_flac_in_archive() {
  set -o localoptions -o pipefail
  local archive=${1?No archive given.}
  ...
}

Or ksh93's (where the pipefail option initially came from):
function mp3_or_flac_in_archive {
  set -o pipefail
  typeset archive=${1?No archive given.}
  ...
}

Where changes to options are always local as long as you use the Korn-style of function definition. Also note that in ksh93, those changes of options (and that's the case of the $archive local variable as well) don't propagate to other functions called within, so your function can safely invoke other functions that expect the pipefail option to be off without doing set +o pipefail themselves.

¹ Even on Unix-like systems where *, ? are as valid characters as any in a file path and filename generation is meant to be done by the shell, unzip also tries reading the file with .zip or .ZIP appended if it can't open the file without and unlike bsdtar doesn't support non-seekable files; it's more of an MSDOS program.
zipinfo, which generally comes with unzip, with its -1 option would also have been a better alternative, though it suffers from the same problems as unzip.

Wow so much info there! Thanks. Didn’t think my post would inspire people so much. 1) Indeed I underestimated the risks with how ZIP tools interpret filenames. Fortunately, most music downloads are sanitized to some extent, but perhaps I should apply my own cleanup tools before to be safe. 2) This is part of a project filled with stuff that assume a Debian / Ubuntu Bash, so I’m OK with local and co. 3) Since this function is called by a bigger script in my context, having empty input there indicates a bug, and exiting the whole script is what I’d want to avoid snowballing.


You’re probably right about my regex being a bit too permissive, thanks. 5) My project already asks for more dependencies than I’d like, so I’ll probably avoid adding BSD stuff into the mix, but I suppose your mentions of them could help people passing by and it’s always nice to learn about new tools. 6) The extra cat to consume the leftovers is a nice trick, and could come in handy elsewhere. 7) Wow, never heard of that local - feature, and it’s not in my help local either. I wonder how you found out about that.


local - was already in the Almquist shell (still the basis for the sh of FreeBSD, NetBSD, Debian) in 1989. I guess I first saw it turn up in the NEWS  file that comes with bash (see /usr/share/doc/bash/NEWS.gz on Debian). You can see it described in info bash local (you may need to install a bash-doc package). The idea is to make the $- special parameter local (though in bash, contrary to ash, not all changes to options change the value of that parameter).

@AliceM. bsdcat/bsdcpio are more CLI interfaces to libarchive (in the libarchive-tools package on Debian), they're not BSD-specific libarchive is maintained as a portable project (contrary to other BSD tools commonly found on GNU/Linux distributions which had to be ported there), libarchive is going to be installed by default at least on desktop installations of Debian as it's used by file-roller (gnome) and ark (KDE) at least. A shame the tools are not installed by default (but then again unzip is not either), bsdtar my go-to tool to deal with archives.

If it's important for the left-hand side command to finish, you could run grep without -q and just redirect the output to /dev/null. The exit status should be the same (but of course grep does some unnecessary work here).
unzip -l "$archive" | grep -iE '.\.(flac|mp3)$' > /dev/null

If it doesn't matter if the left-hand side finishes or gets terminated by the pipe closing, you could just specifically check for the exit status corresponding SIGPIPE and treat it as a zero.
unzip -l "$archive" | grep -q -iE '.\.(flac|mp3)$'
ret=$?
[[ $ret == 141 ]] && ret=0
return "$ret"

In Bash, you could also check the $PIPESTATUS array to check which command fails and with what status.

Interesting approaches, thanks. I suspect the second snippet could even be turned into merely unzip -l "$archive" | grep -q -iE '.\.(flac|mp3)$' || (($? == 141)).

@AliceM. unzip -l "$archive" | grep -q -iE '.\.(flac|mp3)$' || (($? == 141)) would work but also change all failure statuses to 1

Using unzip -l -- "$archive" (or better zipinfo -1 -- "$archive", zipinfo now also available as unzip -Z), as usual would remove the problems with values of $archive starting with -, but not the other problems with those MSDOS-like tools mentioned in my answer.
